# how to subscribe to a UITextView in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, rx-swift, uitextviewdelegate

I am fairly new to IOS development and working on a small project, I am trying to subscribe to UITextView using Rxswift. However, I can't seem to find any way to do so online or by following what I did to UITextField.

this is what I Done and its working for TextField:

```
TextField.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged).withLatestFrom(textField.rx.text.orEmpty)subscribe(onNext : { text in
        self.viewModel.address.accept(text)
Some code goes here
```

Now doing the same thing for a textView

```
TextView.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged).withLatestFrom(TextView.rx.text.orEmpty)subscribe(onNext : { text in
    self.viewModel.address.accept(text)
```

I get the following error:
Referencing instance method 'controlEvent' on 'Reactive' requires that 'UITextView' inherit from 'UIControl'

I am really confused on how to make controlEvent work with UITextField. it doesn't show in the suggested code when I use rx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier than what you have in your question...

```
func example(textView: UITextView, textField: UITextField, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    textView.rx.text
        .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    textField.rx.text
        .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

And the subscribe you have can be much simpler as well:

```
func example(textView: UITextView, observer: PublishRelay<String>, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    textView.rx.text
        .orEmpty
        .bind(to: observer)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

However, keep in mind:

> Subjects [and Relays] provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use. An explanation is in the [Usage Guidelines](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/18_UsageGuidelines.html) in the appendix. Instead of using subjects, favor the factory methods we will look at in [Part 2](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html).  -- [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com)

Break yourself of the habit of binding everything to a Relay or Subject now and you will find your future in Rx much easier.

Comment: Thank you!!! life saver!! this makes it very clear. I will check the usage guidelines to get a clearer idea of the best way to use it.